# Android SDK Cant See Graphical Layout

Tags: android

When I open MainActivity.xml file in my layout folder of android project and click on graphical layout I can see only a gray blank screen. The android UI is not visible in my eclipse. When I searched google and stackoverflow I found I should open the .xml file with android layout editor but this option is not available in my eclipse. And when I tried to add this option from preference I don't find this option.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Preferences -> General- >Editors->File Associations.

   1. If Android layout editor is missing click on Add as shown,
   2. After clicking on Add select Android Layout Editor and then click on OK.
   3. Close Eclipse and restart. Otherwise this will not work.

SECOUND CHANSE I DID TI
1.WORKSPACE FOLDER ALL CONTENT OR FILE DELETE
2. OPEN THE ECLIPS